# Wildcard Search in a collection with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, lodash

I've an array like the one shown below and I want to do a wildcard search and retrieve the corresponding value. This is not returning me any result, can someone help me if there is any better way to do this. I'm using lodash utilities in my nodejs application.

```
var allmCar = [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5833527e25bf78ac0f4ca30e"),
    "type": "mCar",
    "value": "ABDC",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5833527e25bf78ac0f4ca30e"),
    "type": "mCar",
    "value": "XYZ ABD",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5833527e25bf78ac0f4ca30e"),
    "type": "mCar",
    "value": "FGHJ",
    "__v": 0
  }
]

_.find(allmCar, {
  value: {
    $regex: 'XYZ'
  }
})
```

I finally ended up using _.includes as below

```
_.each(allmCar,function(car){
    if(_.includes('XYZ', car.value)===true)
    return car;
})
```

Comment: I think `allmCar` is an array, not an object.

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes you are right, it is an array.

Comment: Are you looking for something like what I have shown in my answer? Because by default regexes cannot be used with `_.find`

Comment: You'll need to specify what "better" means in this context. Also, this question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same with a function passed to `_.find`, like this

```
_.find(allmCar, function(mCar) {
  return /XYZ/.test(mCar.value);
});
```

Or with arrow functions,

```
_.find(allmCar, (mCar) => /XYZ/.test(mCar.value));
```

This will apply the function passed to all the items of the collection and if an item returns `true`, that item will be returned.

Comment: thanks for the response. Will this work for wildcard search? I still don't see it returning any value. What does this .test do, could you please explain.

Comment: @AjaySrikanth [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) checks if the string passed matches the regular expression.